# Android: Spinner dropdown in full screen

Tags: android, android-spinner, android-immersive, android-navigation-bar

I'm trying to open drop down spinner in full screen (immersive mode), but the issue is that when the drop down opens up it brings out translucent navigation bar at the bottom. The navigation bars hides when an option is selected, but remains visible as long as dropdown is visible. 
I was able to remove this behavior in dialog fragment since I have `show(FragmentManager manager, String tag)` method to override and add this

```
getDialog().getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(getActivity()
.getWindow().getDecorView().getSystemUiVisibility());

// Make the dialogs window focusable
 again.getDialog().getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE);
```

but no method similar to this available in spinner. I tried to put these method in `performClick()` using listener implementation in the parent but still no luck.

Any solution to this issue.

Comment: Have you found a solution @UmarHussain?

Comment: no I couldn't find the solution, so I simply accepted this behavior. But where possible I used a list in dialog fragment as an alternative.

Answer (score 3):

**For java users create this static class**

```
import android.widget.ListPopupWindow;
import android.widget.PopupWindow;
import android.widget.Spinner;

public static void avoidSpinnerDropdownFocus(Spinner spinner) {
    try {
        Field listPopupField = Spinner.class.getDeclaredField("mPopup");
        listPopupField.setAccessible(true);
        Object listPopup = listPopupField.get(spinner);
        if (listPopup instanceof ListPopupWindow) {
            Field popupField = ListPopupWindow.class.getDeclaredField("mPopup");
            popupField.setAccessible(true);
            Object popup = popupField.get((ListPopupWindow) listPopup);
            if (popup instanceof PopupWindow) {
                ((PopupWindow) popup).setFocusable(false);
            }
        }
    } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

**For Kotlin user use this extension function**

```
import android.widget.ListPopupWindow
import android.widget.PopupWindow
import android.widget.Spinner

fun Spinner.avoidDropdownFocus() {
try {
    val listPopup = Spinner::class.java
            .getDeclaredField("mPopup")
            .apply { isAccessible = true }
            .get(this)
    if (listPopup is ListPopupWindow) {
        val popup = ListPopupWindow::class.java
                .getDeclaredField("mPopup")
                .apply { isAccessible = true }
                .get(listPopup)
        if (popup is PopupWindow) {
            popup.isFocusable = false
        }
    }
} catch (e: Exception) {
    e.printStackTrace()
}
}
```

You need to call that method from your `spinner` in your `OnCreate` method or when your `Spinner` is inflated or in any time before use it.

```
spinner.avoidSpinnerDropdownFocus()
```

Credits to kakajika GitHub user kakajika
https://gist.github.com/kakajika/a236ba721a5c0ad3c1446e16a7423a63

Comment: works like a charm. remember to use the correct imports depending on version; import androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatSpinner
import androidx.appcompat.widget.ListPopupWindow

Answer (score 0):

Try this code :

```
getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```